# How to remove a struct record from an STL list

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have a list of type `struct` and I want to remove a specific record from that list. What is the best way to do this? I cannot figure out how to do it with `.remove`

```
struct dat
{
    string s;
    int cnt;
};


    void StructList()
    {
        list<dat>::iterator itr; //-- create an iterator of type dat
        dat data1;               //-- create a dat object
        list<dat> dList;         //-- create a list of type dat
        itr = dList.begin();     //-- set the dList itereator to the begining of dList
        string temp;             //-- temp string var for whatever
        data1.s = "Hello";       //-- set the string in the struct dat to "Hello"
        data1.cnt = 1;           //-- set the int in the struct dat to 1

        dList.push_back(data1);  //-- push the current data1 struct onto the dList

        data1.s = "Ted";         //-- set the string in the struct dat to "Ted"
        data1.cnt = 2;           //-- set the int in the struct dat to 2

        dList.push_back(data1);  //-- push the current data1 struct onto the dList

        cout << "Enter Names to be pushed onto the list\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Name ";
            getline(cin,data1.s);   //-- This will allow first and last name
            cout << "Enter ID ";
            cin >> data1.cnt;
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
            dList.push_back(data1); //-- push this struct onto the list.
        }

// I would like to remove the "Ted, 2" record from the list    

        itr = dList.begin();
        dList.pop_front();       //-- this should pop "Hello" and 1 off the list
        dList.pop_front();       //-- this should pop "Ted" and 2 off the list

        //-- Itereate through the list and output the contents.
        for(itr = dList.begin(); itr != dList.end(); itr++)
        {
            cout << itr->cnt << " " << itr->s << endl;
        }
```

Comment: you are not using `remove` in that code, do you?

Comment: See `std::list::remove_if `  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove

Comment: @tobi303, I pulled it because I could not get it to work.

Comment: "//  for some reason this does not work //  dList.sort();" -- and who exactly told you that you can expect "dlist.sort();" to work? C++ never worked this way. This sounds like it's coming from a transplanted Java developer who thinks just because this is how you sort a vector or a list in Java, it must be how this is done in C++.   Well, C++ does not work this way. If you know Java and you're trying learn C++, the best way to do so is to read your C++ book, instead of guessing how to do something in C++ that you know how to do in Java.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, No one told me that, I am new and trying to learn by reading the reference material and experimenting. I got stuck and looking for guidance. So you answered one of my questions, "can you sort a struct list that way". Maybe I can assume that I will not be able to use the `dList.remove();` either. PS. I do not know JAVA either.

Comment: Correct. C++ is arguably one of the most complicated modern programming languages, and it's now, I'd say, is about five times as bigger as it was six years ago. The full C++ language specification runs at about 1400 pages of terse text. The only realistic way to learn C++ is by reading a C++ book. "Experimenting" and making assumptions about how to get things done don't really have a promising chance of success.

Comment: If you are coming in from another language, a good stop-off point is https://isocpp.org/tour to see where you stand on the "Should I get an introductory or intermediate book?" question. If you are coming in fresh, I'll recommend not trusting the Internet. Until you know enough to filter good advice from the bad you don't have the tools to filter the crap that makes up the bulk of blogs, tutorials and other sources of Internet code. There is good stuff out there, but if you don't know what good looks like, you'll waste a lot of time walking bad paths.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Just to be clear, I have a book, reading it. It has one tiny example of an `<int> list`. So I thought I would see how that could work with a `struct` data type, hence the experimenting. Maybe I should have said practicing. either way your input was helpful but now we are off topic as to the original question, how to remove a specific record in the above example. I am not trying to make it do something that is not possible, I am trying to learn and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reference you need to understand for std::list::remove() - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove

If you had a list of something like `int` then just `remove()` would work. In your case though your list contains a struct with no equality operator defined for it. The equality operator is how `remove()` will know when the param passed in matches what's in the list. Note: this will remove all elements that match, not just one.

Your struct with an equality operator would looks something like this:

```
struct dat
{
    string s;
    int cnt;

    bool operator==(const struct dat& a) const
    {
         return ( a.s == this->s && a.cnt == this->cnt )
    }
};
```

Alternately you can remove elements from a list by iterator. In that case you would use `erase()`.

It really depends on what you're trying to do and why you've chosen to use a std::list.
If you're not familiar with these terms then I'd recommend reading up more first.

Comment: That `operator==` should be `const`.  Better, make it a free function.

Comment: Yeah, true. Got that